# Как узнать хост с которого был отправлен запрос?

Tags: c#, proxy, hosts

У меня есть следующий метод, который возвращает WebClient:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webCl = GetWebClient("http", "x.x.x.x", "xxxx");
    webCl.Host // - не работает
}
static WebClient GetWebClient(string type, string host, string port)
{
    using (var web = new WebClient())
    {
        web.Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri($"{type}://{host}:{port}"))
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("BESTproxyshopTG", "proxysoxybot")
        };
        web.Headers.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Application");

        string html = web.DownloadString("http://yandex.ru");
        return web;
    }
}
```

Как мне узнать с какого я хоста отправил запрос на yandex.ru?

Comment: `WebClient` является устаревшим компонентом в C#, об этом сказано в документации. Советую перейти на его замену в лице `HttpClient`. Касательно вопроса: Я лично его не понял. "С какого хоста я отправил запрос" - ну вон у вас `host`, берите это значение. Если вам нужна другая информация о прокси, то не думаю, что сможете ее так просто вытащить. Максимум что сможете вытащить, это заголовки, например `Location`, который ставится, если идет редирект, и обозначает то, куда сайт вас перенаправляет.

Comment: Понял, очень жаль. Просто проблема в том, что я использую несколько прокси и мне необходимо это для логирования. Допустим я отправляю с хоста 127.0.0.1 запрос на yandex.ru, и мне необходимо, вернуть этот же хост, с которого я сделал запрос

Comment: Так у вас переменная `host` и так есть, чего вы еще хотите то я не пойму?

Comment: Как я и писал выше, мне необходимо для логирования и просто для просмотра отладки (всё ли корректно работает)

Comment: И...? Вы сами запускаете уже метод, в который передаете адрес, хост, порт. То есть, хост у вас уже есть, вы его сами задаете, что мешает это использовать для логгирования я не пойму? Напишите в этом методе условно `Log.Trace($"Отправлен запрос на yandex.ru. Proxy: {type}://{host}:{port}")`, ну или делайте это за пределами метода, где задаете `"http", "x.x.x.x", "xxxx"`, ну или если так надо, чтоб метод обратно возвращал входные значения, то возвращайте кортеж или класс, например `return (host, web);`. Короче, мне кажется либо вы нам что-то недоговариваете, либо вы сами не знаете чего хотите.